# Django how to get in model the value from another model

Tags: python, django, wagtail

How to get in django models class Another value of BlogPageGalleryImage image or foreign key or parental key?

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Дата публикации" , default=datetime.date.today  )
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='Лучший')



class BlogPageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(BlogPage, related_name='gallery_images')
    image = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('caption'),
    ]

class Another(BlogPage):
    page = ParentalKey(BlogPage, related_name='instagram_post')
    Image = BlogPageGalleryImage.objects.get(BlogPageGalleryImage.) 
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('caption'),
    ]
```

Comment: Could you be more specific of your question?

Comment: If you want to save `Image` from `BlogPageGalleryImage` in `Another` model then you could overwrite `save()` method, to achive this.

Comment: Are you wanting to set a default for the Another.Image field? It would be helpful if you gave an example of how you are wanting to use it.

Comment: In common I want to get fileds from BlogPageGalleryImage in admin in deafult. For example. There to classes and in one is IMG in another is Text. I need to create third class and get in it Caption and image connected to the other two klasses by foregnkey I think. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I got some results by adding  this image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', default =  BlogPageGalleryImage.objects.first().image_id
    )   , but i dont understand how to filter it to current BlogPageGalleryImage which is assigned to the BlogPage

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking to access the blog page images in your `BlogPage` and `Another` template. This can be achieved by adding the blog page images to the rendering context. To do this override the `get_context` in `BlogPage` method:

```
def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(BlogPage, self).get_context(
       request, *args, **kwargs
    )
    context['images'] = BlogPageGalleryImage.objects.filter(
        page=self,
    )
    return context
```

This means that you can now in your template access the images using `{{ images }}`. So for example:

```
{% for i in images %}
    <div class="image">
        {% image i.image %}
        <p>{{ i.caption }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks, but not in template, I thought to do it in models> but it seems there is no way becaus of philisophy. How can do this in admin interface? In wagtail I usually register views, but it seems in here it's not enough

Comment: By bad, I must have misunderstood your question. Did you try adding an `InlinePanel('gallery_images')` to the `panels` definition of `BlogPage` and `Another`?

Comment: yes I tried, but I dont see my information in fieds from DB  aftre opened the page. I want to open page and see there the values from other foreign model. I think I go wrong way.

Comment: what is the right way to make page which will get information from BlogPage with BlogPageGalleryImage and will make their combine and store information in database(the best is in wagtal\django mode, and if it is possible to make it in admin interface)? What is the best way?